# Is there an antipode of the PHP file() function?

Tags: php, file, file-io

`file()` reads a file into an array reading each line of a file as an element of an array. Is there exactly the same function to write an array into a file?

Comment: No. But it’s not hard to `implode()` an array, and write the resultant string to a file.

Comment: It's the same task though it doesn't mention existance of the `file()`. I don't know if this should be considered duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't exist.

But you can use [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/function.file-put-contents) and [`implode`](http://php.net/function.implode):

```
$file = '/tmp/test.txt';
$data = array('foo', 'bar');
file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $data));
```

**Also** you can also specify the **`$data` parameter as a** single dimension **array**:

```
file_put_contents($file, $data);
```

This is equivalent to:

```
file_put_contents($file, implode('', $data));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there exactly the same function to write an array into a file?

Nope I don't think so.. However you can do something like ..

```
<?php
file_put_contents('yourfile.txt',implode(PHP_EOL,$yourarray));
```